# How to save data in database from shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I want to save user'S data in the db.

Every user's data should be submitted per row without any error. The data is in a function with if else condition. Every if else's output is to be saved against it's user.  How can I do it?

I tried creating a dataframe for it but still the data wasn't saved in it.
Here is reprex of my code.

````
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("my_in","type a value for an entry"),
  actionButton("newline_but","press for a new entry"),
  tableOutput("showmytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
mydf <- reactiveVal(tibble(msg=NA_character_))
  
  output$showmytable <- renderTable({
    mydf()
  })
  observeEvent(input$my_in,{
    local_df <- req(mydf())
    curr_row <- nrow(local_df)
    local_df[curr_row,1] <- input$my_in
    mydf(local_df)
  })
  observeEvent(input$newline_but,{
    local_df <- req(mydf())
      
    mydf(add_row(local_df))
  })
  
  observeEvent(mydf(),
               {
                 #export to a global but would be better to maybe write to a database
                 assign(x="exported_df",
                        value=mydf(),
                        envir = .GlobalEnv)
               })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)```
````

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example of your app

Comment: Updated. Kindly look.

Comment: If you want to write the data to a database you coud use `odbc`. If you host your app on RStudio Connect i would recommend the `pins` package. Other possibilities are `saveRDS`, `writexl`...

Comment: I tried using the dbwritable function. but it's not working properly. The app runs good for quite time but stops working after a while, showing the error- "mySQL server has gone away [2006] in R shiny". When I comment the dbwritable function it works fine. The db is cuurently in aws and being used by other application as well.  I am still not getting the idea where I am going wrong.